# Collapsible Power App Sections

Tags: javascript, powerapp

I have an app that includes form elements that users fill out and submit to a Sharepoint list.

However, since there are many form fields to fill in users have complained about the app requiring too much scrolling and being too long. They would like to have collapsible sections that contain related datacards. Currently, I have a form element within my screen with a list of all the related data cards where users enter responses. I need to split it into different subjects and each subject expands when an down arrow is pressed.

I have followed this tutorial : [tutorial](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ux-patterns-expander-control-with-expand-collapse-animation/) - which is exactly what I want - but I want each section to contain the related datacards. Is it possible to have form datacards in each of these sections? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This would work fine, though you'd have to put separate forms into each section, rather than a collection of data cards. You could then submit all the forms together via the patch function.